# Ethernet isn't show correctly on GUI

Tags: networking, kernel, user-interface, ethernet

I've updated my kernel recently and that got Ethernet support all messed up (meaning: the hardware was saw by the system, but I couldn't connect to any network). I fixed that by including the parameters on /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

That got the Ethernet working again after a reboot.

But the GUI isn't showing this, as you can see in my screenshot. It says the connection has failed and it doesn't recognize the connection, even though I'm using it right now to post this.[image]

I'm willing to bet that I have to inform some config file about the enp3s0 being my Ethernet port, but I don't have any idea which file would that be.

If anyone has an idea, it'd be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this by myself. What I did was:

First, I purged r8168-dkms completely from my system (it was bundled with an older kernel):

```
sudo apt purge r8168-dkms
```

After this I downloaded the r8168 from Realtek's website. It is a tar file with a autorun.sh on it. Just decompress it into a directory and run the sh.

It'll give you SSL errors, but it should install the driver afterwards.

Lastly, you should blacklist the r8169, which is a open source alternative driver, as far as I can understand:

```
echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

After all this, you can reboot and you should regain Ethernet conectivity. You can run `lshw -class network` in order to see if the driver is correctly installed and if the interface is working properly.

There is a lot of things about issues with this particular driver on different distros (Ubuntu and Arch based, as far as I could find) and of all things I've tried, this did the trick.